# Is my question of "passenger aspects" or what is the closure reason?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I understand, that [my question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30789/3230) is off-topic, but to avoid future misunderstandings, I'd like to know, why or how it is off-topic? Was it closed because of being of "[passenger aspects](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"?

Should I really ask questions like that (i.e. which kind of aircraft is used or given passenger route) on Travel.se? Because, that sounds to me a little bit suspicious and I'm getting a very big feeling, that this question asked there will be marked off-topic as well, with a note to ask it here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your guess is exactly right. This is a community of pilots, air traffic controllers, aerodynamic engineers, mechanics, and other people who are interested in aviation as an activity - whether professional, or as a hobby. It's not a site for searching for commercial flights, and people here are not interested in helping you find or book air travel.

I can't tell you whether your question is on-topic for Travel - it's very localised and unlikely to be of help to any other visitors - but they definitely shouldn't tell you to ask it here. A question being off-topic on one site doesn't automatically make it on-topic for another site. The Stack Exchange network doesn't aim to provide a home for every possible question.

Comment: That being said, I think that they might accept it at Travel.  Certainly closer to being on topic there rather than here.

Comment: I agree that it's tenuous at best here, but I think it seems on topic for Travel. Looks like the migration was accepted. I've added relevant tags to it on Travel.